# Multi-monitor, multi-video card in Ubuntu Studio

Tags: nvidia, ubuntu-studio

I'm contemplating the possibility of moving most of my stuff over to linux (I do web development on windows, so I'll still have to keep a VM for that, but for everything else, Ubuntu Studio is looking real nice). I do a lot of podcast recording, writing, managing of blogs (Hexo, ftw), and the like.

I went through my software packages today, and of those I don't use exclusively for development, all had acceptable (or better) linux equivalents, or were cross platform, save one (evernote, which can live in a windows VM for now). So I got an ubuntu studio download, burned an ISO, and started playing. It LOOKS fairly straightforward, but one thing I wasn't able to figure out with the LiveCD was how to get a multi-monitor, multi-video card setup working. I could see all 4 monitors in the dropdown list (but only two in the little layout window), yet when I turned off mirroring, I had one screen that was by itself, and the other three screens mirrored each other.

Every time I've looked at linux as an option, driver issues have turned me back, but it's never been this close to working. Both cards are NVidia GeForce GTX 660's. Anybody have any hints on what this could be? I tried using newer NVidia drivers from the settings. I've not yet done the install to disk, as I really need to see it working from the live CD to feel comfortable making a commitment.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `xrandr` command line tool. It is harder to use than any GUI configuration system, but it lets you set up whatever multi monitor workspace your drivers can handle.

Run it without parameters to see what displays the system has available.

Then, for example, if you have monitors A, B and C from left to right, you can run: `xrandr --output A --auto --output B --auto --right-of A --output C --auto --right-of B`. Don't forget `--auto` after each output to have each display turned on and set to its optimum resolution. `--above` and `--below` also work as you might expect.

Comment: It's gotten weirder now. No matter what version of linux boot disk I use (I tried OpenSuse, Mint, Ubuntu, and UbuntuStudio), It only seems to detect three displays now where it previously detected four. One of the monitors simply never turns on, while two of the remaining appear to be mirrored (appearance-wise). Then after a bit, the system locks, both on the nouveou (sp?) driver and on the nvidia one.

Any ideas?